# How do you get started with a new Xero API application? I get a blank screen with three blinking dots when I login to myapps area

Tags: xero-api

Am I missing a step in the API account registration?

Comment: Is there a specific tutorial you are following? Is there a specific step your having issues with? Any code you can share?

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually caused by browser's session.

Can you try to clear your browser's cookies & cache or perhaps use a different browser?

Another thing that you can try is using the browser with incognito mode.